# Blogger main page filter posts on labels

Tags: filter, blogger, label, posts

I need some help with filtering out posts based on labels (displaying only posts with a certain label) on the main page of Blogger on a custom template that has the follow code:

```
<b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>
    <b:if cond='data:post.isDateStart'>
      <b:if cond='data:post.isFirstPost == &quot;false&quot;'>
        &lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
      </b:if>
    </b:if>
    <b:if cond='data:post.isDateStart'>
      &lt;div class=&quot;date-outer&quot;&gt;
    </b:if>       
    <b:if cond='data:post.isDateStart'>
      &lt;div class=&quot;date-posts&quot;&gt;
    </b:if>
    <div class='post-outer'>
    <b:include data='post' name='post'/>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;static_page&quot;'>
      <b:include data='post' name='fn_comment_picker'/>
    </b:if>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
      <b:include data='post' name='fn_comment_picker'/>
    </b:if>
    </div>        
  </b:loop>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
<b:include data='post' name='post'/>
```

with

```
<b:if cond='data:post.labels'>
<b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
<b:if cond='data:label.name == &quot;YOUR LABEL&quot;'>                                                
<b:include data='post' name='post'/>
</b:if>
</b:loop>
</b:if>
```